# Unable to see all the tags in the next tag badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

Maybe this is not the right place to ask this kind of question (sorry i this is the case).

I'd like to know why in my `Activity User Page`, under the section `Reputation, Next tag badge`, if I click on Choose which bag to tack I can not see all my top tag. In other words, as you can see the three screens look different. I don't know if this is a bug anyway, why this is happening? What I'm missing?

---

Screen 1:
[image]

Screen 2:
[image]

Screen 3:
[image]

Comment: One is showing all tags, one is showing recommended tags, one is showing top tags. Can you state more clearly which of those you think is wrong and why? Screen 1 shows 8 tags (one with a zero next to it), screen 3 shows 6 tags which are your higher scoring ones.

Comment: @NickGammon I think that Screen 2 should report also sound, pulse and arduino-pro-mini. Am I wrong? It looks like the system is not keeping the count of the score for those three tag.

Comment: On my "choose tags" display there is a scroll bar on the right. I can't tell from your screenshot whether you have one (and didn't notice it) or not.

Comment: @NickGammon there isn't any scroll bar. This is way I'm asking, I tried also to use the search tool for the particular tags that are missing, but with no more results than the three displayed in the Screen2.

Comment: I think you are confusing *Tags* and *Badges*. Screens 1 and 3 are for Tags, screen 2 says "Search for a badge".

Comment: @NickGammon, maybe I was asking the question in a not understating way. Anyway, the answer of Oded explain what I was asking. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bunch of those tags are not eligible for becoming tag badges yet - a tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.

The tag badges you cannot track are those that are not eligible to tag badges.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.